# $A$ be a convex subset and $D$ be dense in a real NLS ; then for every non-empty open subset $U$ of the NLS , $U\cap D\cap V \ne \phi$?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a convex subset of a real normed linear space $V$ and $D$ be a dense subset of $V$ ; then is it true that for every non-empty open subset $U$ of $V$ , $U\cap D\cap A $ is non-empty ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the set $A$? It was defined but never used.

Comment: @ajotatxe : I have edited ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $V = \mathbb R^2$, $A$ a line segment, $D = V \backslash A$.

Comment: Simpler only "$A$ is a point" :) By the way, is the empty set convex? Then $V=D=\{0\}$, $A=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

First, $U\cap D\cap V=U\cap D$ because $U\subset V$.

Second, any non-empty open subset of $V$ intersects $D$, precisely because $D$ is dense in $V$ (this is a definition of dense subset).

So yes, $U\cap V\cap D$ is non-empty.

Note that we have only used the topology of $V$. There's no need of linearity, convexity, norm, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take $V=C[0,1]$ with the uniform norm, $A$ is the subspace of all polynomials (convex), $D=C[0,1]\setminus A$ (dense). But $A\cap D=\emptyset$.